# How to upload huge number of xml files to ADLS or DBFS from UI or CLI in a faster way. Any suggestions would be really appreciated?

Tags: databricks, azure-storage-account

I have around 50 k xml files which I wanted to upload to ADLS/DBFS. Can this can be uploaded as a zip file and work on zip file from ADLS/DBFS. As of now its taking so much of time for uploading into ADLS/DBFS.
I use dbfs cp -r which is not effective in this case.
Also trying to upload through Databricks UI. Same case when trying to upload through storage explorer to ADLS
Looking forward to valid suggestions:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) or [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to upload to ADLS. They use multiple upload threads and may end up being faster than `dbfs cp -r` which uploads files one by one.

Comment: I tried with Azure Storage Explorer. But copying 50 k files into the folder the took more time compared to dbfs cp -r . I am looking forward to some other means to keep the folder as zip and extract the zip with in dbfs or adls.I think it should be possible right.

Comment: If you choose to upload compressed files use one of the supported formats (bzip2, gzip, lz4, snappy) instead of zip. Reading them will be just `spark.read.format("xml").load(path_to_directory)`.